# Users Complain that Xamarin Android App Freezes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-play-console

I have a Xamarin.Forms Android app on the Google Play store. An overwhelming amount of users are leaving 1 star app reviews of my app saying that the app is "Freezing." They say that nothing happens when they click on a button in the apps UI. I have made doubly sure that no processes are running on the UI Thread that might hold up the UI. I have not been able to recreate this "Freezing" behavior personally. There are also no crash or ANR reports in the Google Play Console (at least not enough to make up for the amount of negative reviews I'm receiving). Has anyone else faced this problem?

Useful Info:
Xamarin.Forms Version: 4.8.0.1560
There is no discrimination between the Freezing behavior and users' Android API Version
The issue is not happening (or is not being reported) on the iOS app.

Comment: have you added any logging around the parts of the app they are complaining about?

Comment: I have. However, I'm only getting successful logs. Which makes me think it is something with Xamarin. I can't catch the error or what is causing the user to 'hang up.'

Comment: It's hard for us to find out the cause without any relevant code and we can't reproduce it. I would recommend you to ask for more information from the user and test in the release mode by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a physical Android device to deploy to? Take the apk and side load it, or download from the store, don't use VS to deploy the app on your device.

I had a similar issue and it was the code shrinker in VS. The released version with the code shrinker enabled, caused the app to freeze immediately after the splash screen.

You can disable it by selecting 'nothing' in the code shrinker box in VS.